# How to install ZBar for C on Debian

Tags: debian, zbar, installation-package

I am trying to install ZBar library on my Debian.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZBar

First I tried to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools zbar-dbg libzbar-dev
```

Unfortunately it seems that it installed the `0.10` version which hasn't been developed since 2012 and perhaps this is the reason why it does not work well.

There is a newer version available here https://github.com/mchehab/zbar but I have no idea how to install it from github. I tried to follow the `INSTALL.md` but it doesn't make sense for me. For example it says to run configure shell script while there is no such file available?!

Could anyone please tell me step by step how to install this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in INSTALL.md, you should try

```
autoreconf -vfi && ./configure
```

This generates *configure* and runs it.
after that, try

```
make
```

EDIT:
of course, you should clone the project first

```
git clone https://github.com/mchehab/zbar
```

and then cd into it

```
cd zbar
```